# A concise way to not execute a loop now that C-Style for loops are going to be removed from Swift 3?

Tags: swift, for-loop, range

Imagine we have this code which works perfectly for `n >= 0`.

```
func fibonacci(n: Int) -> Int {
    var memo = [0,1]
    for var i = 2; i <= n; i++ {
        memo.append(memo[i-1] + memo[i-2])
    }
    return memo[n]
}
```

If I remove the C-style for loop [due to upcoming changes to Swift 3.0](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md), I get something like this:

```
func fibonacci(n: Int) -> Int {
    var memo = [0,1]
    for i in 2...n {
        memo.append(memo[i-1] + memo[i-2])
    }
    return memo[n]
}
```

While this works fine for `n >= 2`, it fails for the numbers `0` and `1` with this error message:

> fatal error: Can't form Range with end < start

What's the most concise way to fix this code so it works properly for `0` and `1`?

(Note: It's okay, and even desirable, for negative numbers to crash the app.)

---

**Note:** I realize I could add a guard statement:

`guard n >= 2 else { return memo[n] }`

... but I'm hoping there is a better way to fix just the faulty part of the code (`2...n`).

For example, if there was a concise way to create a range that returns zero elements if `end < start`, that would be a more ideal solution.

Comment: I think that the `guard` solution would be the most appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this in a way that works for n < 2, you can use the `stride` method.

```
let startIndex = 2
let endIndex = n

for i in stride(from: startIndex, through: endIndex, by: 1) {
    memo.append(memo[i-1] + memo[i-2])
}
```

Comment: You are right! I hadn't thought of that. (There is a comma missing between the  arguments. You could also directly write `for i in 2.stride(through: n, by: 1)`.)

Comment: @MartinR Fixed, thanks. I used the separately named constants to try to make the example more self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any shorter way to do this though? e.g. through extension or override ... etc, because the for loop is quite common and the stride is quite long...

Comment: @hyouuu For many cases you can just use the range operators `...` and `..<` as in `for i in start ..< finish {  }`. I would save `stride` for loops that can't be expressed easily with ranges.

Comment: @MarcKhadpe I think the reason why this question was brought up by the author was that in many cases we wouldn't know if start will be <= end, which unfortunately would cause a crash whereas stride and classic for loop would be no-op

Comment: `start.stride(through: end, by: gap)` is being replaced by `stride(from: start, through: end, by: gap)` in Swift 3.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily create a valid range with the `max()` function:

```
for i in 2 ..< max(2, n+1) {
    memo.append(memo[i-1] + memo[i-2])
}
```

This evaluates to an empty range `2 ..< 2` if `n < 2`.

It is important to use the `..<` operator which *excludes* the upper bound because `2 ... 1` is not a valid range.

But in this function I would simply treat the special cases first

```
func fibonacci(n: Int) -> Int {
    // Let it crash if n < 0:
    precondition(n >= 0, "n must not be negative")

    // Handle n = 0, 1:
    if n <= 1 {
        return n
    }

    // Handle n >= 2:
    var memo = [0,1]
    for i in 2 ... n {
        memo.append(memo[i-1] + memo[i-2])
    }
    return memo[n]
}
```

(Note that your `memo` array is set to the initial value `[0, 1]`
for each function call, so the values are not really "memoized".
Without memoization you don't need an array, it would suffice to keep the last two numbers to compute the next.)

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the variable `i` will always be equal to the `count` of the memoizing array, so you can just use that as your loop condition:

```
func fibonacci(n: Int) -> Int {
  var memo = [0,1]
  while n >= memo.count {
    memo.append(memo[memo.count-1] + memo[memo.count-2])
  }
  return memo[n]
}
```

Alternatively, you could express the loop as a recursive function:

```
func fibonacci(n: Int) -> Int {
  var memo = [0,1]
  func rec(i: Int) -> Int {
    if i >= memo.count { memo.append(rec(i-2) + rec(i-1)) }
    return memo[i]
  }
  return rec(n)
}
```

Really, though, `if` is the best solution here. `Range`s don't allow the end to be smaller than the beginning by design. The extra line for:

```
func fibonacci(n: Int) -> Int {
  if n < 2 { return n }
  var memo = [0,1]
  for i in 2...n {
    memo.append(memo[i-1] + memo[i-2])
  }
  return memo[n]
}
```

Is readable and understandable. (To my eye, the code above is better than the `for ;;` version)

Answer (score 0):

@Marc's answer is great: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34324032/1032900

But the stride syntax is too long for frequent usage, so I made it a little more pleasant for the common i++ usages...

```
extension Strideable {
  @warn_unused_result
  public func stride(to end: Self) -> StrideTo<Self> {
    return stride(to: end, by: 1)
  }
}

extension Strideable {
  @warn_unused_result
  public func stride(thru end: Self) -> StrideThrough<Self> {
    return stride(through: end, by: 1)
  }
}
```

So use like this:

```
for i in startPos.stride(to: endPos) {
  print("pos at: \(i)")
}
```