# for in loop with where clause in Swift

Tags: swift, for-in-loop

I have tried to update a little function to Swift 2.1. The original working code was:

```
import func Darwin.sqrt
func sqrt(x:Int) -> Int { return Int(sqrt(Double(x))) }

func sigma(n: Int) -> Int {
    // adding up proper divisors from 1 to sqrt(n) by trial divison
    if n == 1 { return 0 } // definition of aliquot sum
    var result = 1
    let root = sqrt(n)
    for var div = 2; div <= root; ++div {
        if n % div == 0 {
            result += div + n/div
        }
    }
    if root*root == n { result -= root }
    return (result)
}
print(sigma(10))
print(sigma(3))
```

After updating the for loop I get a runtime error for the last line. Any idea why that happens?

```
import func Darwin.sqrt
func sqrt(x:Int) -> Int { return Int(sqrt(Double(x))) }

func sigma(n: Int) -> Int {
    // adding up proper divisors from 1 to sqrt(n) by trial divison
    if n == 1 { return 0 } // definition of aliquot sum
    var result = 1
    let root = sqrt(n)
    for div in 2...root where n % div == 0 {
            result += div + n/div
    }
    if root*root == n { result -= root }
    return (result)
}
print(sigma(10))
print(sigma(3)) //<- run time error with for in loop
```

Comment: Since you are updating your code, you might want to change `if n == 1 {return 0}` to `guard n != 1 else { return 0 }`

Comment: Using `stride()` is another option, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323227/a-concise-way-to-not-execute-a-loop-now-that-c-style-for-loops-are-going-to-be-r.

Comment: @ramkrishna-sharma Don't tag with "ios" questions that are not directly related to iOS. Swift is also supported by OS X and now Linux; Swift questions may apply and are not specific to iOS. In short: Swift ≠ iOS. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you pass `3` to `sigma`, your range `2...root` becomes invalid, because the left side, the `root`, is less than the right side, `2`.

> The closed range operator `(a...b)` defines a range that runs from `a` to `b`, and includes the values `a` and `b`. The value of `a` must not be greater than `b`.

`root` is assigned `sqrt(n)`, which means that in order for the `2...root` range to remain valid, `n` must be above 2<sup>2</sup>.

You can fix by supplying a lower limit for the right side, i.e.

```
for div in 2...max(root,2) where n % div == 0 {
    ...
}
```

However, at this point your solution with the regular `for` loop is more readable.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I did expect that the for-in-loop would not be executed at all. Fixing the upper bounds by finding the maximum of upper and lower bounds is semantically different. I will follow your advice and keep the regular for loop.

Comment: @Tiza However, note that the regular C-style loop will get removed from Swift in Swift 3.0 so if you rewrite it now, it will save you time later. See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md You might want to use another `for` loop variant or a `while` loop.